# align checkbox with first line of label and prevent wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox and its label in a div like this:

```
<div>   
    <input style="float:left;" type="checkbox" id="check_1" name="check_1" value="" />  
    <label style="margin-left:20px;display:inline-block;float:left;" for="check_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque magna at purus vehicula, vitae tristique lorem euismod. Etiam convallis urna eget vehicula vulputate. Proin mauris orci, auctor ut neque sed, pharetra tempor leo. Donec sit amet nulla orci. Aliquam volutpat volutpat urna, vitae fermentum nunc bibendum id. Aenean tincidunt auctor interdum. Aliquam aliquet libero non convallis pharetra. Integer consectetur tellus placerat pretium elementum. Nam vulputate odio sed commodo placerat. Integer sagittis, diam vel tristique sagittis, dui nisl rutrum diam, et vestibulum orci mi vestibulum purus. Aenean tempus semper ipsum sit amet tincidunt. Nunc ultricies congue nisl, vitae varius erat eleifend ac. Sed ultricies orci ante, ac semper purus luctus sed. Praesent malesuada velit id nisi pulvinar dignissim. Aenean eleifend faucibus risus, at auctor quam. Pellentesque non porta feliu</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to align the checkbox with the first line of the label and prevent the label text from wrapping underneath the checkbox. As you can see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WkXHX/1/), I tried floating the checkbox to the left of the label and add a margin-left to the label, but that did not work. There are other answers to similar questions like that but all of them have the input element inside the label tag (I don't want that). Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: +1 for using the `for` attribute :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display: block` on the label rather than `display: inline-block`;

```
<div>   
    <input style="float: left;" type="checkbox" id="check_1" name="check_1" value="" />  
    <label style="margin-left: 20px; display: block; float: left;" for="check_1">L...</label>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkXHX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<input style="vertical-align:top;" type="checkbox" id="check_1" name="check_1" value="" />  
<label style="display:inline-block; width: 400px;" for="check_1">Lorem</label>
```

**Demo** - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvt2c/)

Answer (score 0):

only providing width to both the elements will sort your work out.
try this: [jfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GLMZT/1/)

```
<div style ='width:100%;' >   
    <input style="width:5%;float:left;" type="checkbox" id="check_1" name="check_1" value="" />  
    <label style="width:85%;float:left;margin-left: 20px;" for="check_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque magna at purus vehicula, vitae tristique lorem euismod. Etiam convallis urna eget vehicula vulputate. Proin mauris orci, auctor ut neque sed, pharetra tempor leo. Donec sit amet nulla orci. Aliquam volutpat volutpat urna, vitae fermentum nunc bibendum id. Aenean tincidunt auctor interdum. Aliquam aliquet libero non convallis pharetra. Integer consectetur tellus placerat pretium elementum. Nam vulputate odio sed commodo placerat. Integer sagittis, diam vel tristique sagittis, dui nisl rutrum diam, et vestibulum orci mi vestibulum purus. Aenean tempus semper ipsum sit amet tincidunt. Nunc ultricies congue nisl, vitae varius erat eleifend ac. Sed ultricies orci ante, ac semper purus luctus sed. Praesent malesuada velit id nisi pulvinar dignissim. Aenean eleifend faucibus risus, at auctor quam. Pellentesque non porta feliu</label>
</div>
```